# Spring Boot: Restart programtatically including VM and program arguments and classpath

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

We have a spring boot web application that we start with a modified, extended start command similar to this:

```
java -classpath "..." -Dlogging.config="..." org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher --debug --spring.config.location="..."
```

Now, we need to restart this application programatically (e.g. via an endpoint), but we need to ensure that the "same start command is used".

I found this [solution on bealdung](https://www.baeldung.com/java-restart-spring-boot-app#restart-by-creating-a-new-context):

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    private static ConfigurableApplicationContext context;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        context = SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    public static void restart() {
        ApplicationArguments args = context.getBean(ApplicationArguments.class);

        Thread thread = new Thread(() -> {
            context.close();
            context = SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args.getSourceArgs());
        });

        thread.setDaemon(false);
        thread.start();
    }
}
```

In this case, the program arguments can be extracted with the bean ApplicationArguments.

So far I did not find a way to do the same for VM arguments and also the extension of the classpath as seen in the command above.

Is that even possible? Is there a more convenient way to restart a spring boot application with all these requirements in mind?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way you've found in tutorial does not restart the whole JVM process, it closes the application context and re-creates it. This means that all the beans get loaded again which is logically equivalent to restart as far as all the objects are managed by Spring or course.

There as also a way of making such a restart without writing custom code - use Spring Boot's actuator that has a `restart` endpoint. You can invoke the endpoint and the application will be restarted in the same sense as you've described. See [this tutorial for example](https://javapointers.com/spring/spring-boot/how-to-restart-spring-boot-automatically-using-actuator/) there are many others.

In both of the ways, there will be the same JVM process (jvm does not restart), so both classpath and JVM parameters will remain just the same (do not change).

So if you want to restart the JVM you can wrap the long command into some sort of script (like bash if you're working on linux, or *.bat file for windows for example).

Other than that spring boot can't help much - from this perspective its a regular java application.

Comment: I see! That clears the question for the VM arguments as I understand that they are not reset by this kind of restart and thus are still present. What about the classpath extention? does that go in the same direction?

Comment: In general yes, classpath is something that you supply to th jvm process before it starts. In spring boot application you can also build a jar with all the dependencies inside and then start it with `java -jar app.jar`

Comment: Its possible to load java classes on the fly with custom classloaders, but its pretty advanced stuff so I dont think you need to deal with that unless there is ni other choice...

Comment: Unfortunately, we cannot use the actuator approach here :-( We used the classpath extension instead of a "fat" jar because of an external configuration process we need to stick to. But in general: Thanks for the info :-) Can you add the point that JVM arguments stay as is with a restart. Then I can accept the answer :-)